# issue with HTTP vs HTTPS on soap service via SQL server

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, sockets, soap

I have a SOAP service hosted on a web server (2012 R2). This SOAP service was getting called by a SQL server and everything worked fine.

I moved this SOAP service to a different web server (2016). Now the same SQL server call is getting failed when I am using "https". Although, everything works fine when I use "http"

When I send a soap call using ARC client on my local machine with https, I get desired result.

My SOAP service is .NET framework 4.6.2 (TLS level on the server supports 1.1 and 1.2)

Additional information:
SOAP service is a virtual site under a parent Application.

So,
https://sitename/servicename/mobileservice.asmx - Fails
http://sitename/servicename/mobileservice.asmx - Passes

Please let me know if someone faced a similar issue and could figure out why.
Below is the error I get

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
System.IO.IOException: 
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Pro
    ...
System.Net.WebException: 
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Comment: My gut feel is that it's because they can't agree on encryption

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used wireshack to trace the connection and found that SQL server is sending this request using TLS1.0 and Web Server has only TLS1.2 enabled. Although, when I force my SQL server to force the TLS connection to 1.2 it errors out saying "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Comment: I think you need to add more info to your post; it's not even clear what version of SQLS you have, or what [patches have been applied](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server) in the name of getting this working